# Change firefox panel color using userChrome.css

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, css

I am using two different Firefox profiles, and I need to distinguish between them. I would like to modify one of them, so that the panel has different color. I don't want to install any additional addon or theme, I would like to achieve that using `userChrome.css` only.

I have found [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Tutorial/Modifying_the_Default_Skin) site, where they describe the various components/elements. But I am unable to find the one that changes the color of the whole upper panel.

At the moment I don't have any theme installed, and Firefox is using "Default" Appearance, which in effect just takes over colors from my environment (Openbox).

I have tried adding the following into `userChrome.css`, but it changes the color of the menu only:

```
menubar {
  background-color: red;
}
```

How can I change the color of the whole Panel (menu + Toolbar + ...)

## UPDATE:

The following code suggested by @Srinidhi works well, but does not color the whole window:

```
menubar, toolbar, nav-bar, #TabsToolbar > *{
  background-color: rgb(102,66,60) !important;
}
```

How can I color the whole window, including the menu background, or pop-up windows, such as when I click `Edit -> Preferences` ?

Comment: Open `chrome://browser/skin/browser.css`, perhaps that'll provide a clue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the following:

```
menubar, toolbar, nav-bar, #TabsToolbar > *{
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

Tested this on Firefox 28. With this change, the individual tabs will not be colored red. If you want even those in red, then add this:

```
.tabbrowser-tabs * {
  background-image: none !important;
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

If you don't use `background-image` then you'll still see the borders of the tab which is actually an image.

Comment: this works great, thanks. The only problem is that the red color does not display in the whole menu bar. I mean the bar at the very top. The red color ends where the menu text ends. I.e. Only the left half of the bar is red. The right side is still the default color.

Comment: I've been trying to figure out how to theme the right side of the menubar. From what I can see, there's no "element" after the menubar. But I'm not an expert in XUL.

Comment: any idea how I could color the whole menu bar, not just under the text? Also, is there any way to color the rest of the window, such as the color of the window that pops op when I click `Edit -> Preferences` ?

Answer (score 0):

1. about:config
2. browser.uiCustomization.state
3. "dirtyAreaCache":[...]
4. *barlabel* {background: solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;}

Comment: there is no item `browser.uiCustomization.state` in my `about:config`.

Comment: My bad. I forgot about the new Australis UI, which I thoroughly despise. I installed Classic Theme Restorer, which gives me back UI elements by their old tag names. You may want to look up Australis.