# Change firefox menu color using userChrome.css

Tags: firefox, colors, firefox-extensions, css

I would like to expand on [my question](https://superuser.com/questions/817983/change-firefox-panel-color-using-userchrome-css) , which I asked on superuser few weeks ago. As the question was formulated, the answers were satisfactory, and I have accepted. But it turns out, it does not solve my whole problem.

I now have following code in my `userChrome.css` and the toolbar and menu background have my custom color:

```
menubar, toolbar, nav-bar, #TabsToolbar > *{
  background-color: rgb(102,66,60) !important;
}
```

But I need to change the background of the whole window frame, ie all panels and popup windows, such as when I click `Edit -> Preferences`

Can somebody please advise how to color the whole firefox window with my custom color ?

I am using Firefox 24.8.1 (Iceweasel) on Debian Wheezy. I would also like to apply the same solution to Thunderbird (Icedove).

## CLARIFICATION:

I need to achieve this using `userChrome.css`. I don't want to change the whole desktop Theme for all applicatiopns. I am using two separate firefox profiles, and I need them to look diferently so that I can tell them apart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
* {
  background-color: red !important;
  -moz-appearance: none !important;
}
```

Tested this on Firefox 26.0 - menus, URL bar, About dialog, etc., all show up in `red`.

I hope you choose a 'better' color than `red`. The above change will make **everything** `red` - except for content area.

Comment: indeed it changes the color of everything. This is a huge progress ! But unfortunately it changes the shape of the window elements as well, and some frames/boundaries disappear, which makes the whole interface confusing and unclear. I can post some screenshots, in case it is not clear what I mean. I have tested it on Thunderbird, with color `rgb(102,66,60)`.

Comment: most noticeable effect is with menu. The menu completely merges with the panel/background, looses frame/boundary which makes it very hard too distinguish.

Comment: is there anything we can do to fix the problem, which I describe in the comments above?

Comment: Can you find the element in question that you want to add a border to, and add CSS: `element {border: 1px solid #CCC}` ?

Answer (score 0):

Firefox inherits those colors from Windows.  If you change them in Windows, they will change in Firefox.

Comment: RockPaperLizard@ - I ask specifically how to do it using `userChrome.css`.

Comment: That changes things!  I now understand that you want to differentiate between two profiles using visual cues.  Changing colors is a good way to do it.  I would have to look at the FF source code to figure out if it can be done.  If I get some free time, I will (no promises!).  In the meantime, you can try 3 things: (1) use an extension to change the title bar (if you don't run maximized), or (2) arrange the toolbar with different icons in each profile to provide a visual cue.  But you've already changed the color of the toolbar, so you are probably looking for something more intense.  cont...

Comment: (continued) ... or (3) move the toolbar (urlbar) to a different position to differentiate each profile.  It will be hard to miss the toolbar at the bottom instead of the top, for example.