# Change firefox menu color using userChrome..css

Tags: firefox, thunderbird, colors, firefox-extensions, css

From my [previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/826865/change-firefox-menu-color-using-userchrome-css), I have following content in my `userChrome.css`:

```
menubar, toolbar, nav-bar, #TabsToolbar > *{
  background-color: rgb(102,66,60) !important;
}
```

This changes the color of the main toolbar in Thunderbird to red.

I need to color the toolbar in the compose window as well. I.e. When I click on "write" to compose new email, a new window opens. Apparently, the toolbar is called differently, because the above rules do not change color.

By toolbar, i am referring to the bar at the top, where the buttons are 
`Send, Spelling, Attach, save, ...`

**How can i change the color of the compose window?**