# coloring firefox using userchrome.css - get rid of two rectangles

Tags: firefox, colors, firefox-extensions, css

Regarding this thread:
[Change firefox panel color using userChrome.css](https://superuser.com/questions/817983/change-firefox-panel-color-using-userchrome-css)

I would like to color my firefox, but only the top bar. The Bar where the buttons and tabs are. (Australis)

I already colored the bar, but there are two rectangles left and right which are not colored.
Could you help me coloring these, without coloring anything else?
(Or removing them)

[image]

```
menubar, nav-bar, #TabsToolbar > *{
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try playing with the margins, changing its values, like:

```
menubar, nav-bar, #TabsToolbar > *{
  background-color: red !important;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
}
```

(maybe negative values will do it)

If you can't get it right, download the [DOM Inspector add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dom-inspector-6622/) to analyze your browser's chrome.

Comment: The DOM Inspector plus Element Inspector did it.                menubar, nav-bar, #navigator-toolbox, #TabsToolbar > *{
  background-color: red !important;
}